# Impedance RLC circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, complex-numbers, inductance

Why is the impedance of the inductor defined as $i\omega L$, and of the capacitor $\frac{1}{i \omega c}$ ? More generally, why are they complex numbers? Is impedance a mere mathematical tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Impedance can be seen as an analogy to resistance. As a simple example, if we consider a resistor connected in series to a voltage source, we have $R=V_R/I$

We can do the same thing for a pure inductor hooked up to an alternating voltage source. If $V(t)=V_0\cos(\omega t)$ for example, then $V_L=-V_0\cos(\omega t)=L\dot I$ which then indicates that $$I(t)=-\frac{V_0}{\omega L}\sin(\omega t)=-\frac{V_0}{\omega L}\cos\left(\omega t-\frac\pi2\right)$$

Comparing the maximum of the voltage and the current, we see that the ratio for the inductor quantities $V_\text{max}/I_\text{max}=\omega L$, which is almost what we want. But why is there the imaginary number $i$ in the impedance? Well, this is because, as you can see, the current is also phase shifted compared to the voltage. As a rule of thumb, whenever you are dealing with trig functions with different phases, you should instead work with complex numbers where the phase is encoded in the amplitude.

Indeed, we can do the same thing working with complex values, and then understanding that we can take the real part at the end to work with actual physical quantities. So let's say $V(t)=V_0e^{i\omega t}$, then $V_L=-V_0e^{i\omega t}=L\dot I$ which indicates that $$I(t)=-\frac{V_0}{i\omega L}e^{i\omega t}$$ And this give us $V_L/I=i\omega L$ which is a better analogy with resistance.

Note that if we took the real part of $I(t)$ we would get the same result as before, but now the phase shift is encoded in the $1/i$ in the amplitude. This is why we use complex impedance: it takes into account the "resistance" and the phase shift due to the circuit element(s). A similar analysis can be used on the capacitor.

> More generally, why are they complex numbers? Is impedance a mere mathematical tool?

For circuits, I would say yes, complex numbers are just a very useful mathematical trick. One could only do the math with trig functions and trig identities relating various phase changes. The math would be harder and less intuitive, but it could be done.

Answer (score -2):

The equation for the voltages in a driven RLC circuit can be put into the form:

```
   I Z cos(wt+ϕ) = I Xc cos(wt – π/2) + I R cos(wt) + I XL cos(wt + π/2)
```

Where I is the maximum current, Z the impedence, Xc the capacitive reactance (1/wC),  XL the inductive reactance (wL), and w the angular frequency.  (One or more of these terms may be missing in a simpler circuit.) (The I's can be divided out.)  Either way, this equation resembles the equation for adding the x components of three vectors to get the x component of the resultant vector.  In this visualization, the vectors are all rotating around the origin of an xy coordinate system with an angular velocity w, but the x components continue to indicate the voltages on the related circuit elements. To simplify calculation of  Z and  ϕ, the vectors are generally sketched at t = 0.    In more advanced courses you may see the visualized vectors placed in the complex number plane, and represented by imaginary exponential functions. As in this case, only the real components represent voltages (or wave displacements)  [Note:  Comparison of power series expansions shows that e^i wt = cos(wt) + i sin(wt).]  If the vectors are sketched in the complex number plane and frozen at t = 0 then the vector representing XL is in the direction of +i and Xc is toward -i.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting mathematical expressions.

Comment: I'm too old to learn a new language. My word processor does superscripts and subscripts. It would help if your system would accept them.

Comment: Alright, no worries. But MathJax is very easy, just add `$` and `$$` signs around formulae for inline and centered math mode respectively. The page I linked has more information on it. It would be quite a nice *"adventure"* to learn MathJax. Also, don't let your age limit your capacity :-) FWIW, there isn't any rule i the system to necessarily use MathJax, but using Mathjax is always preferred since it makes mathematical expressions easy to read, and lack of MathJax will necessarily result in some downvotes in the cases where the lack of MathJax is detrimental to the post.